# What is the correct call for lists

Tags: python-3.x

Why is every time I set a variable as a list, it always comes back as TraceBack error when I try to append to the list:

```
>>> a = list
>>> a.append('item1')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: descriptor 'append' requires a 'list' object but received a 'str'
```

```
>>> type(a)
<class 'type'>
```

`list` is not the attribute to define lists but it is a method to convert to lists. It is explained [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_list.htm).

What is the python attribute to define a variable as a list?

Answer (score 3):

To initialize a var with a certain type, use () after the name of the class:

```
a = list()
```

Comment: or better a list literal `[]`

Comment: Sure both would work but to cope with his solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can also instatiate a list like this:

`mylist = []`